# Heroku nodejs/mongoose and mLab app crash with timeout

Tags: node.js, heroku, mongoose

Below is the output of heroku logs. I tried setting connection parameters

```
    socketTimeoutMS: 0,
    connectionTimeout: 0
```

but still occures

```
[web.1]: events.js:160
[web.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[web.1]:       ^
[web.1]: 
[web.1]: Error: connection timeout
/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection.js:169:17)
........
[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-105-generic
/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.9.5
[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

Comment: what version of mongoose are you using and what's the mongodb version also on mlab

Comment: are you sure you have given correct address and authentication password for mongo labs?

Comment: @RaviShankar Yes. Even it used to work before.

Comment: @FemiOladeji mongoose 4.8.3 currently after running `npm update` and even before I update the problem was there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted mLab for that. That's the response of their support personnel:

> We often suggest a 30sec connection timeout when connecting from Heroku. You can see our suggested Mongoose config here:
>   https://gist.github.com/mongolab-org/9959376

Below is the connection configurations in that github gist:

```
// mongoose 4.3.x
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

/* 
 * Mongoose by default sets the auto_reconnect option to true.
 * We recommend setting socket options at both the server and replica set level.
 * We recommend a 30 second connection timeout because it allows for 
 * plenty of time in most operating environments.
 */
var options = { server: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 300000, connectTimeoutMS: 30000 } }, 
                replset: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 300000, connectTimeoutMS : 30000 } } };       

var mongodbUri = 'mongodb://user:pass@host:port/db';

mongoose.connect(mongodbUri, options);
var conn = mongoose.connection;             

conn.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));  

conn.once('open', function() {
  // Wait for the database connection to establish, then start the app.                         
});
```